# Display 2 featured items per page within 10 results of pagination

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating a property listing website in Codeigniter. On the listing page, I displayed 10 results with pagination, but on top of each page, I wanted to show 2 featured property listing and 8 normal listings.
I mean to say that on 1st page 2 featured listings on top and then 8 normal listings. Then again on the 2nd page, other 2 featured listings on top and 8 normal listings.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks in advance for what?

Comment: For your help. if you can :)

Answer (score -1):

First, I think you should include your code to get a better understanding on how you have done things.

What I got from your question, I can think of the following solution:
You should differentiate between your listings (say 0 for normal 1 for featured) with a field in your database. Then get them in two different arrays and loop through them. For normal 8 per page and for featured 2 per page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I set 0 for normal and 1 for featured. And I also tried with two different arrays. But I thought its the wrong method.

Comment: are you not getting your desired result or you are facing errors?

Comment: I got with this method, but I am looking for a single SQL query and single array.

Comment: Ok than. Get all the data in one array.
Put an IF condition for listing check (whether normal or featured).
Have a count for both normal and featured and see to it that featured does not exceed 2 and normal does not exceed 8 on a single page.

Comment: But what if in the result of the SQL query will have no featured listing within 10 records?

Comment: In your property listing data, are you only responsible for data entry, I mean only admin will be doing data entry OR every user could create account and add a property?